# What are some good Oracle Db maintenance Tools

Tags: database, oracle

We have grown from a small time of 2-3 developers to about 30 developers very quickly. We supposedly never needed Source Control, or Db Monitoring or Schema diagrams.

Now we see more and more terrible code being moved to the Production. Is there an off the shelf product for oracle that will help manage version control and deployment management from Test, to UAT, to Prod?

Also nice to have would be Schema diagrams, Documentation Tools, some amount of performance profiling capabilities. But primarily would like to a tool to manage code source control and Migration for oracle scripts, DDL, DMLs etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I srongly recommend getting Oracle'e [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html). This integrates with Subversion, provides an overview of the entire database, including procedures, schema changes and so on. This will make your life easier.

Comment: I might try SQL developer again, a year ago, it was bloated buggy piece of software. Though it was still a beta, it seemed like it had been in Beta forever with no improvement.

Comment: It's getting better. I haven't used it for integrating with version control, but I have used it to extract DDL fairly easily.

Comment: The current version is 1.5.4. I have no complaints about it, it does everything I ask of it with minimal swearing. It is written in Java (everything oracle produces is Java these days) which results in some people saying no.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) for your source control and management of scripts, DDLs and etc?  Our ORACLE DBAs use it here and they swear by it.

Comment: We use SVN for to maintain source control, but I wanted something more in "touch" with the database. Is there a software you know of thats linked more closely to oracle. ?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am *very* late to this party, however, I wanted to draw your attention to our product, dbMaestro TeamWork for Oracle, which provides exactly the functionality required here.  We offer the functionality equivalent to source control tools for Oracle artifacts.  Many companies use SCM by proxy (as suggested above by northpole, re using SVN), our solution is "in touch' with the database as required by Reuben on the original post.  To read more please visit our site at http://www.dbmaestro.com or e-mail us at info@go-esi.com.

Disclosure - My company represents this product in the US.

Answer (score 0):

TOAD (by Quest Software) is fantastic and includes most of what you want including source control.

Comment: are you talking about the Toad for Dba's ? We use Toad For Oracle, which lacks the source control, unless its an add- in or something.